# How to modify the Ansible-galaxy timeout while installing roles from git

Tags: git, ansible, connection-timeout, ansible-galaxy

I have a little heavy Ansible role in Git which I am trying to install in my local using ansible-galaxy but I am getting CRC check failed error may be because connection is timing out while downloading the role. Is there a way to increase the ansible-galaxy timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no timeout value for `ansible-galaxy` import process. [The code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/cli/galaxy.py#L605) waits infinitely for `git` task status to become either `SUCCESS` or `FAILED`.

You can try adding `--no-wait` option to the `ansible-galaxy import` call which will return the control to the shell and let the import process finish in background, but I'm afraid CRC error comes from `git` and it can't be helped.

You can always try to import the role using `git import` directly in the CLI.

Comment: Yes it seems to be underlying git problem and not an issue with ansible-galaxy